# как заменить объект в массиве объектов?

Tags: javascript, redux

Есть изначально вот такая конструкция

```js
{
  books: [
    {
      id: '200',
      author: '4124',
      name: '412',
      imgUrl: 'data:image/jpeg;base64'
    }
  ]
}
```

Нужно как-то пройтись по массиву объектов в свойстве `books`, и заменить объект в массиве тем, который проходит по `id`, и затем вернуть новый объект со свойством `books`, в котором мы заменили объект,не изменяя старый объект.

Т.е. по итогу должно вернуться новый объект

```js
{
  books: [
    {
      id: '200',
      author: 'new author',
      name: 'new name',
      imgUrl: 'some img'
    }
  ]
}
```

Возвращаем новый объект со свойством `books`, но как заменить объект и добавить в массив я что-то не знаю.

```js
const changedItem = action.book
return Object.assign({}, state, {
                books: state.books.map(item => item.id === changedItem.id ? changedItem : item)
            });
```

Comment: Изучай методы обхода свойств объекта и элементов массива. for ... in и forEach соответственно и делай перебор. Здесь свойства перебирать не нужно, только элементы массива.

Comment: @Дмитрий у меня и перебираются объекты в массиве books посредством map....

Answer (score 1):

Если я ваc правильно понял, то должно это вроде выглядеть так:

```js
    var object = {
      books: [
        {
        id: '200',
        author: '4124',
        name: '412',
        imgUrl: 'data:image/jpeg;base64'
        }
      ]
    };

    function replace(object, searchID){
    var replacedObject = object;
    for(var i = 0;i<replacedObject.books.length;i++){
        if(replacedObject.books[i].id != searchID) continue;

        replacedObject.books[i].author = 'newAuthor';
        return replacedObject;
      }
    }
    alert(replace(object, 200).books[0].author);
```

старый объект при этом не меняется, а новый можно заносить в переменную вызовом функции
у меня выводит вместо 4124 - newAuthor

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.books.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
if(item.id == "200") {
   Object.books[i] = {id: "200", ...} // Новый объект с новыми свойствами
   // Или так Object.books[i].author = "..."; и так для каждого изменяемого свойства
}
})
```

Comment: Object нельзя перебрать, это конструктор.
В моем примере он используется для того чтобы создать новый объект и скопировать в него все свойства старого объекта state в котором находится свойство books тем самым не изменяя старый object и создавая новый. Это конечно моя оплошность что не дописал по поводу `не изменяя старый объект`.

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться методом reduce. Что-то вроде:

```
books.reduce((acc, book) => {
  if (book.id === id) {
    return [...acc, { ...book }]; // меняй любые свойства в объекте
  }
  return [...acc, book];
}, []);
```